# Webpack: unable to require automatically resolved dependencies using variables

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, webpack

While working on a Web app using Webpack to manage JavaScript dependencies, I stumbled upon the problem i'm going to describe.

Loading dependencies passing strings to `require()` works beautifully:

```
// main.js
var jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Here, `jquery` is installed with Bower, and Webpack is correctly configured to automatically resolve Bower modules.

Now, I'm working on the problem of conditionally loading modules, with particular regard to the situation where modules have to be downloaded from a CDN, or from the local server if the CDN fails. I use `scriptjs` to asynchronously load from the CDN, by the way. The code I'm writing is something like this:

```
var jQuery = undefined;
try {
  jQuery = require('jquery-cdn');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Unable to load jQuery from CDN. Loading local version...');
  require('script!jquery');
  jQuery = window.jQuery;
}

// jQuery available here
```

and this code works beautifully as well.

Now, since I obviously have a lot of dependencies (Handlebars, Ember, etc.) that I want to try to load from a CDN first, this code starts to get a little redundant, so the most logical thing I try to do is to refactor it out into a function:

```
function loadModule(module, object) {
  var lib = undefined;
  try {
    lib = require(module + '-cdn');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot load ' + object + ' from CDN. Loading local version...');
    require('script!' + module);
    lib = window[object];
  }
  return lib;
}

var jQuery = loadModule('jquery', 'jQuery');
var Handlebars = loadModule('handlebars', 'Handlebars');
// etc...
```

The problem is that Webpack has a [particular](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/325#issuecomment-46995239) [behaviour](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) when dealing with expressions inside `require` statements, that hinders my attempts to load modules in the way described above. In particular, when using an expression inside `require` it

> tries to include all files that are possible with your expression

The net effect is a huge pile of error messages when I try to run Webpack with the above code.

Though the linked resources suggest to explicitly declare the path of the JavaScript files to include, what I fail to get is how to do the same thing when I cannot, or don't want to, pass a precise path to `require`, but rather use the automatically resolved modules, as shown.

Thanks all

### EDIT:

I still don't known how to use expressions to load those scripts, however, I designed a workaround. Basically, the idea is to explicitly write the `require('script')` inside a callback function, and then dinamically call that function when it's time. More precisely, I prepared a configuration file like this:

```
// config.js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  'lib': {
    'jquery': {
      'object': 'jQuery',
      'dev': function() { require('script!jquery'); },
      'dist': function() { return require('jquery-cdn'); },
      'cdn': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'
    },
    'handlebars': {
      // ...
    }
  }
};
```

Inside my main code I, then, define an array of resources to load, like:

```
var config = require('./config.js');
var resources = [ config.lib.jquery, config.lib.handlebars, ... ];
```

And then when I have to load the development version, or the distribution version, I dinamically call:

```
// Inside some kind of cycle
// resource = resources[index]
try {
  window[resource.object] = resource.dist();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Cannot load ' + resource.object + ' from CDN. Loading local version...');
  resource.dev();
}
```

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/michelezamuner/exercise-ember/overview) there's a more complete example of this in action.